# Blender 3.5 how to control guide hairs?

Tags: hair

I'm trying the new Hair system and I've run into an issue with it. How do I tell this new hair system to follow vertex groups? I don't see a field in any of the modifiers created.

Because I'm trying to apply fur to an animal character, and fur is growing out of the mouths, eyes, etc.

How can I control it like the old system?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Let's suppose you have created a vertex group with the name "Hair boundary". Then find the geometry node called "Interpolate Hair Curves", and click that icon and type the name as the following screenshot:

[image]

By this way, the hair will no longer grow outside of the area defined by the vertex group.

Comment: I did not know you could use a vertex group! Makes things a lot easier! Thanks!